Select query in SQLAlchemy with mypy - Argument 1 to "where" of "Select" has incompatible type "bool"; expected "ColumnElement[bool]
When querying some params in an endpoint:
duplicate_integration = select(Integration).where(
        integration_create.provider_accounting_id == Integration.provider_accounting_id,
        integration_create.provider_webshop_id == Integration.provider_webshop_id,
        Integration.user_id == user.id,
    )

(integration_create here is a variable referencing a pydantic schema, while Integration is the SQLAlchemy model)
This gives the following error when type checking with mypy:
syncly/api/integrations.py:64: error: Argument 1 to "where" of "Select" has incompatible type "bool"; expected "ColumnElement[bool] | _HasClauseElement[bool] | SQLCoreOperations[bool] | ExpressionElementRole[bool] | TypedColumnsClauseRole[bool] | Callable[[], ColumnElement[bool]] | LambdaElement"  [arg-type]

What is wrong with my approach? And how might I solve it?

I suspect mypy expects the arguments to be in the reverse order, where(sqlalchemy_model.column == pydantic_model.column).  (SQLAlchemy may expect the same,

Actually SQLA doesn't care about the order of the arguments.
